# How to choose an element from a sublist randomly in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, oop

I wanted to make batches of 5 in my list for which I used:

```
data = ['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','p8','p9','p10','p11','p12','p13','p14','p15','p16','p17','p18','p19','p20']    
def test_batches(patients, n):
        for i in range(0, len(patients),n):
            yield patients[i:i+n]
    #define your batch size (n) over here:
    n=5 #example
    
    x = list(test_batches(data,n))
    print(x)
```

this prints:

```
[['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5'], ['p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9', 'p10'], ['p11', 'p12', 'p13', 'p14', 'p15'], ['p16', 'p17', 'p18', 'p19', 'p20']]
```

How do I `randomly` choose one "p" from each of sublist here using Python?

```
required output: [p3,p9,p11,p20]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the facilities available in the random module?

Comment: Yes I did. also I know I can print it by using the index in the sublist. but I am struggling with choosing that index randomly.

Comment: This is an **interactive** community. Interact with the community so they can tell if your question has been answered. If an answer meets your needs accept the answer. If your question has not been answered add comments. Possibly clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice
data = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9', 'p10', 'p11',
        'p12', 'p13', 'p14', 'p15', 'p16', 'p17', 'p18', 'p19', 'p20']


def test_batches(patients, n):
    for i in range(0, len(patients), n):
        yield patients[i:i + n]
    # define your batch size (n) over here:


n = 5  # example

x = list(test_batches(data, n))
print(x)
items_from_sublist = []
for sublist in x:
    items_from_sublist.append(choice(sublist))
print(f'{items_from_sublist=}')
```

Testing Output:

```
[['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5'], ['p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9', 'p10'], ['p11', 'p12', 'p13', 'p14', 'p15'], ['p16', 'p17', 'p18', 'p19', 'p20']]
items_from_sublist=['p3', 'p6', 'p14', 'p17']
```